# Using loop arrays to store user input in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell-3.0

I am currently trying to powershell script that will allow users to input a list of servers that will be added a collection and then parsed into XML.  I've never tried to loop in Powershell, the ISE doesn't have an immediate window, so I can't see if my array is actually being built. Can anyone validate that this code will work?

```
$Reponse = 'Y'
$ServerName = $Null
$ServerList = $Null
$WriteOutList = $Null

Do 
{ 
    $ServerName = Read-Host 'Please type a server name you like to minitor. Please use the server FQDN'
    $Response = Read-Host 'Would you like to add additional servers to this list? (y/n)'
    $Serverlist = @($ServerName += $ServerName)
}
Until ($Response -eq 'n')
```

Comment: Validate? Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how do I check to see may array is actually storing objects?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the array is not storing string values is because the syntax is incorrect. To add new strings in an array use the += operator after the string you want to insert.

1. Declare the empty array with "$Serverlist = @()" (declaring is not required when not running scripts in strict mode)
2. Add new strings to the array using the "+=" operator
3. Ouput the array using the "Write-Output" cmdlet

As Is

```
$Reponse = 'Y'
$ServerName = $Null
$ServerList = $Null
$WriteOutList = $Null

Do 
{ 
    $ServerName = Read-Host 'Please type a server name you like to minitor. Please use the server FQDN'
    $Response = Read-Host 'Would you like to add additional servers to this list? (y/n)'
    $Serverlist = @($ServerName += $ServerName)
}
Until ($Response -eq 'n')
```

To Be

```
$Reponse = 'Y'
$ServerName = $Null
$Serverlist = @()
$WriteOutList = $Null

Do 
{ 
    $ServerName = Read-Host 'Please type a server name you like to minitor. Please use the server FQDN'
    $Response = Read-Host 'Would you like to add additional servers to this list? (y/n)'
    $Serverlist += $ServerName
}
Until ($Response -eq 'n')

Write-Output $Serverlist
```

Regarding your script, I cannot help wonder why you want to have user input? The whole point of Powershell is to automate as much as possible. I would recommend to use import-csv cmdlet and refere to a file which contains all your server names.

Importing using Import-CSV

```
$ComputerNames = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\serverlist.csv' -Header 'Computer'
Write-Output $ComputerNames
```

Note: It will import using PSCustomObject and not an Array

CSV File Example

```
Server1
Server2
Server3
Server4
```

Note: Just type all the servers in notepad ending with a carriage return after the server name.

Finally check out this cheat sheet from PowershellMagazine. It contains useful commands, operators, arrays, ... This helped me also allot during the first days of powershell scripting.

Url: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/1/2/2122F0B9-0EE6-4E6D-BFD6-F9DCD27C07F9/WS12_QuickRef_Download_Files/PowerShell_LangRef_v3.pdf